# CMake - Switch between multiple versions of a directory

Tags: cmake

I'm new with CMake. I have to adapt a CMakeLists.txt file in the following way:

The projects has several subdirs, one which we'll call "subdir" from now.
The rest of the ( C++ based ) code can include files from this directory using the "#include" syntax. Now what I basically want to do is provide multiple versions of subdir (subdir1, subdir2 etc.) and switch between them using a CMake variable. However, for the code this switch should be transparent, it only sees a directory "subdir". It should be made sure that gcc notices the switch though and rebuilds everything if the variable is changed.

What would be the best way to achieve this in your opinion? Should work at least on Windows and Linux.

Regards

Comment: Since they are mutually exclusive, let each subdirectory expose a target with the same name and control which one you `add_subdirectory` via a cache variable. Put `INTERFACE` properties on the target as needed via, e.g. `target_include_directories(... INTERFACE ...)`.

Answer (score -1):

To develop what @alex-reinking proposed in the comment.

In the `CMakeLists.txt` you can selectively choose the directory to include at configure time with something like:

```
# expose cmake option to control the subdir
option(USE_IMPL "The implementation subdir" defaultSubdir)

# include it
add_subdirectory("${USE_IMPL}")

target_include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${USE_IMPL}")
target_link_libraries(TheTarget library_target_in_subdir)
```

Comment: There is no such command as `add_directory` or `target_include_directory`.

Comment: @AlexReinking thanks for pointing it out, I wrote a sort of sketch to come back later, and then I moved on to another thing